# How can i get list of options of some attribute of products in one of the categories in wordpress+woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want to make this thing - get a list of options of some attribute of products in category with known id. So, the category id is *$catid*, the attribute is *$attr*.

So, to my mind, i have to do these steps:
0) get all the products ids from category with id

1. get all attributes of products with these ids
2. if product's attribute is *$somename*, get it's option, store it in array *$options*

Finally there must be an array like [s,m,l,xl,xxl] for example, if the searching attribute is "size" and the category is "t-shirts".

So what is done:

```
function get_options_of_attribute() {
$catid = "6776"; // T-shirts
$attr = "size";
$all_ids = get_posts( array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'     =>  $current_cat_id,
        'operator'  => 'IN'
          )
       ),
   ));
   $ids = '';
   $values = '';
   foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
       $ids .= $id.' ';
       foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $id, $attr ) as $attribute_value ){
    $values .= $attribute_value.' ';
}
   }
```

//  return $ids;

```
  return $values;
}

add_shortcode( 'listofoptions', 'get_options_of_attribute' );
```

Nothing happens. The part of code, which generates the $ids is working, something wrong with wc_get_product_terms() i think...

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved it with:

```
    function get_options_of_attribute() {
$current_cat_id = "6776"; // T-shirts
$attr = "size";


$all_ids = get_posts( array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'     =>  $current_cat_id,
        'operator'  => 'IN'
          )
       ),
   ));
   $ids = '';
   $value = array();
   $values = '';
   foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
       $ids .= $id.' ';
       $value[] = wc_get_product_terms($id,'pa_'.$attr, array( 'fields' => 'names'))[0];
   }
$uniquevalue = array_unique($value);

 foreach ( $uniquevalue as $uv ) {
$values .= $uv.' ';
}

return $values;

}

add_shortcode( 'listofoptions', 'get_options_of_attribute' );
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for solution. In my case it returned only 2 out of 8 terms. For debugging I made it display found taxonomies in a category, so here's fixed script:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', function() {
        $current_cat_id = "335"; // Adjust the category ID accordingly
        $attr = "size";

        $all_ids = get_posts([
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => $current_cat_id,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ]
            ],
        ]);

        $values = [];
        foreach ($all_ids as $id) {
            // Fetch all terms for each product
            $product_terms = wp_get_post_terms($id, 'pa_' . $attr, ['fields' => 'names']);
            if (!is_wp_error($product_terms)) {
                $values = array_merge($values, $product_terms);
            }
        }

        $unique_values = array_unique($values);

        // Echo unique values separated by space
        echo implode(' ', $unique_values);
    
});
```